# how can I set a a style on an anchor tag that has focus?

Tags: css

For the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="#user-stacks" data-toggle="tab">My Stacks </a>
```

how can I add a style for this tag after it receives focus?

I have tried:

```
 li.section-tab a:focus {
color: cadetblue;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

Comment: try `li.section-tab > a:focus` which means the `a` tag directly under that li

Answer (score 0):

Keep the locator simple and understandable, here is the working code

```
a:focus {
color: cadetblue;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

Comment: This will apply style to all achor tags what if he wants for specific anchor tag ? Also this is not a answer it's a suggestion, you should put it in comments

Comment: what does this  `li.section-tab` mean, where are these selectors in the HTML code he mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `:active` ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active)). Usually it would be same style you use for `:hover`, so:

```
li.section-tab a:active,
li.section-tab a:hover {
    color: cadetblue;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

> When interacting with a mouse, this is typically the time between the
>   user presses the mouse button and releases it. The :active
>   pseudo-class is also typically matched when using the keyboard tab
>   key.